# is_equal operator in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equality

I have two NumPy ndarrays `a` and `b`. I want to check if they are equal as if `a=b.copy()`. However, if I use the `==` operator it returns an element-wise list of `True` or `False`. I want a binary answer, i.e. if all the elements are equal in terms of value, type, etc then a single `True` should be returned else `False`. Is there an operator in NumPy to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function won't serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
np.array_equal(a,b)
```

or alternatively:

```
(a==b).all()
```

Also, depending on your application and array dtype, I would suggest checking `np.allclose` and `np.array_equiv` too.

Comment: could numpy.allclose() be a better alternative?

Comment: @MohitLamba As I have mentioned in the post, depends on your dtype in array. If your array is an `int` array for example, `array_equal` works fine, but if it is `float`, `np.allclose` is better alternative to deal with floating point precision.